# Result is not displayed in TextView. Android. Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a problem like this.
I made a loop that sums up the cost of my subscriptions, but I ran into the problem that the TextView does not display the result of the sum of all subscriptions. Tell me what I did wrong?
Thanks in advance for your help!

```
class ListFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentListBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var mSubViewModel: SubViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root

        binding.floating.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_listFragment_to_addFragment)
        }
        total()


        //добавить меню
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        //recyclerView
        val adapter = ListAdapter()
        val recyclerview = binding.recycler
        recyclerview.adapter = adapter
        recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())

        //SubViewModel
        mSubViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SubViewModel::class.java)
        mSubViewModel.readAllData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { sub ->
            adapter.setData(sub)
        })

        return view


    }

    private fun total(): Int {

        val total = 0
        val subList = emptyList<Subscription>()
        for (subscription in subList) {
            total += subscription.priceSub
            binding.totalTv.text = total.toString()

        }


        return total
    }

}

private operator fun Int.plusAssign(priceSub: String) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention that you are creating an **empty list** in `total()` function:

```
val subList = emptyList<Subscription>()
```

So the total price is 0.

You need to use non-empty list, which contains some `Subscription`s with prices to be able to calculate total price.

So I guess you need to add parameter to the function, and pass a subscriptions list when calling it:

```
mSubViewModel.readAllData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { sub ->
        adapter.setData(sub)
        binding.totalTv.text = total(sub).toString()
    })

private fun total(subList: List<Subscription>): Int {
    var total = 0
    for (subscription in subList) {
        total += subscription.priceSub
    }
    return total
}
```

Comment: Fixed but shows 0. Also fixed emptyList to ArrayListOf, but the amount is not displayed

Comment: You can edit your question to show what you've done to better understand.

Comment: did according to your example, but it still shows 0

Comment: There's no reason it shouldn't work if you made these changes (except ``total`` needs to be a ``var`` or it won't compile, did you post your actual code?) - are you sure that ``total`` function is actually getting called with any data?